# Pandas groupby and get nunique of multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as below

```
stu_id,Mat_grade,sci_grade,eng_grade
1,A,C,A
1,A,C,A
1,B,C,A
1,C,C,A
2,D,B,B
2,D,C,B
2,D,D,C
2,D,A,C

tf = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

My objective is to

a) Find out how many different unique grades that a student got under `Mat_grade`, `sci_grade` and `eng_grade`

So, I tried the below

```
tf['mat_cnt'] = tf.groupby(['stu_id'])['Mat_grade'].nunique()
tf['sci_cnt'] = tf.groupby(['stu_id'])['sci_grade'].nunique()
tf['eng_cnt'] = tf.groupby(['stu_id'])['eng_grade'].nunique()
```

But this doesn't provide the expected output. Since, I have more than 100K unique ids, any efficient and elegant solution is really helpful

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Comment: How about `tf.groupby('stu_id').nunique()`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - Thanks for your suggestion. In sample I didn't give additional columns but in real data, there are additional columns. So, nunique for all columns is not required. but yes, useful to know from you that it can be done for whole dataframe as well

Comment: If you have multiple columns in that case you can filter the required columns using: `tf.filter(like='_grade').groupby('stu_id').nunique()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify columns names in list and for column `cols` call [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with `rename`:

```
cols = ['Mat_grade','sci_grade', 'eng_grade']
new = ['mat_cnt','sci_cnt','eng_cnt']
d = dict(zip(cols, new))
df = tf.groupby(['stu_id'], as_index=False)[cols].nunique().rename(columns=d)
print (df)
   stu_id  mat_cnt  sci_cnt  eng_cnt
0       1        3        1        1
1       2        1        4        2
```

Another idea is used named aggregation:

```
cols = ['Mat_grade','sci_grade', 'eng_grade']
new = ['mat_cnt','sci_cnt','eng_cnt']
d = {v: (k,'nunique') for k, v in zip(cols, new)}
print (d)
{'mat_cnt': ('Mat_grade', 'nunique'), 
 'sci_cnt': ('sci_grade', 'nunique'), 
 'eng_cnt': ('eng_grade', 'nunique')}

df = tf.groupby(['stu_id'], as_index=False).agg(**d)
print (df)
   stu_id  mat_cnt  sci_cnt  eng_cnt
0       1        3        1        1
1       2        1        4        2
```